# How to adjust widget to compact mode

Tags: ios, ios10, today-extension

I've got some troubles with new format of Today Extensions. It's ok in the extended mode it, but the compact mode is a real pain. I can't get how this compression mechanism works. In my case a small font and top of view just disappears, its not what i like to see.

I've tried to change frame of self.view and make some items hidden, but no sence. 
Anyone else had same? How can I fix it?

Comment: In compact mode, the widget has a height of 110. It cannot be less than this even if you programatically set the height less than 110.

Answer (score 0):

don't put constraints on the bottom on your view... maybe is the reason why your top is being squizzed due to priorities... 
in code, resize your own view as per your calculated content height (like tableview.count*height_row + otherview.height), set that height to the preferred content size in expanded mode, and you should be fine with expanded/collapsed.

else put some code...